# What is the purpose of RegionUpdater?

Tags: forms

All address form template files call `new RegionUpdater` in the end of file. For example template\customer\form\address.phtml has following line:

```
new RegionUpdater('country', 'region', 'region_id', countryRegions, undefined, 'zip');
```

What exactly this RegionUpdater does? Why it does it and how ? Is it necessary?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**tl;dr** Yes. You need it; if you want valid data from your customers.

You asked what it *is*, and what it *does* - Let's start at the top:

`RegionUpdater` is defined in `js/varien/form.js`, around line 167 (ca. Magento 1.6+). It is a class to **provide mapping of required fields** for regions in address forms. It also **handles showing/hiding fields** based on the **configured options** in Magento admin panel.

```
RegionUpdater = Class.create();
```

It provides 3 main methods - **initialize**, **update**, **setMarkDisplay**. To describe what they do, in general:

**Initialize**

Initialize takes 6 arguments:

```
    this.countryEl = $(countryEl);
    this.regionTextEl = $(regionTextEl);
    this.regionSelectEl = $(regionSelectEl);
    this.zipEl = $(zipEl);
    this.regions = regions;
```

The `$()` method is an element selector in Prototype.js.  If `disableAction` is of type `undefined`, then it defaults non-required fields to hide them - otherwise it uses the method passed. This could be anything including additional validation.

Initialize calls `update` when the country select dropdown changes. (~line 184).

**Update**

Some regions have fields that aren't required, such as Postcode. Others have undefined regions that require you to type in the region by hand, as it may not have a dropdown (select, option) pair.

Update is called from initialize and basically goes to a lot of trouble to **keep track of countries that have dropdown region types** or require an input text box for you to type it yourself. It handles required / disabled fields as well in the process.

Update calls setMarkDisplay at the end of its logic and passes in the `regionSelectEl` element.

**SetMarkDisplay**

This basically just checks if the `regionSelectEl` element is **required** and if it has a value if so, or has a span or parent element with a class called **required**. This is what displays the message "This is a required field" when you forget to put valid data into the form.

If validation is set on a field and you did not enter data into it correctly, it adds the class name `required-entry` to input element which displays the warning to the user.

**In closing**:

What is it? It's a sophisticated class that shows/hides/disables/enables fields based on configuration values and data provided from the user. It also handles marking up required fields for address validation.